# Find out name of graphics card driver in a C++ OpenGL program

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm searching for a way to find out the name of the currently used graphics card driver inside a C++ OpenGL program. At best would be a platform-independent way (Linux and Windows). The only thing I could find was [this](http://linux.koolsolutions.com/2009/04/24/tip-how-to-check-which-video-driver-is-your-x-server-using/) but that's a shell solution and might even vary along different distributions (and still, Windows would be a problem).

I already looked at glGetString() with the GL_VENDOR parameter, however that outputs the vendor of the graphics card itself, not the driver. I couldn't find any options/functions that give me what I want.

Is there an easy solution to this problem?

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish with the driver name?

Comment: @chill: nope, that gives me the exact name of the graphics card.

Comment: @genpfault: There's a bug in a program, that only occurs when the linux open-source Nouveau driver for Nvidia is used. The bug is easily solvable if I know that this driver is used.

Comment: Did you ever find a way of detecting Nouveau from a C++ program? Nouveau remains a serious problem for OpenGL code so being able to detect it and do something else if it is the driver is a common need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the ultimate answer, but it might help you. You can work out the driver name and version combining both the `lsmod` and `modinfo` commands, under Linux.

For example, my `lsmods` returns the following:

```
$ lsmod 
Module                  Size  Used by                
autofs                  28170 2  
binfmt_misc             7984  1  
vboxnetadp              5267  0  
vboxnetflt             14966  0  
vboxdrv              1793592  2 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt  
snd_hda_codec_nvhdmi   15451  1 
snd_hda_codec_analog   80317  1  
usbhid                 42030  0  hid
nvidia              11263394  54
```

from which I know that nvidia refers to the graphics card.

I can then run `modinfo nvidia` and I get

```
filename:       /lib/modules/2.6.35-32-generic/kernel/drivers/video/nvidia.ko
alias:          char-major-195-*
version:        304.54
supported:      external
license:        NVIDIA
alias:          pci:v000010DEd00000E00sv*sd*bc04sc80i00*
alias:          pci:v000010DEd00000AA3sv*sd*bc0Bsc40i00*
alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc02i00*
alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc00i00*
depends:
```

And I can extract the driver version etc...

I know this is neither a straight forward solution nor multiplatform, but you might work out an script that extracts driver name and versions if you guess that most of names will be nvidia, ati, intel etc... by grep / awk the output of `lsmod`.

Comment: Thanks for this elaborate answer, that helped me.

Comment: @bobbel Can you accept the answer or give it an up vote at least? This may help others!

Comment: whops, sorry for the late answer! Should turn on email notifications :D

Answer (score 3):

Try these:

```
const GLubyte* vendor = glGetString(GL_VENDOR); 
const GLubyte* renderer = glGetString(GL_RENDERER); 
const GLubyte* version = glGetString(GL_VERSION);
```